# Does Tornado close connection at the end of request?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

When I am working with Tornado and on the end of get/post request I have return statement or I don't have anu return at all ( no even self.write ) does it close connections ?
(when I type into command line  netstat -tanp | wc -l I got a lot of connections, like not alive, only existing ). Does it close connection at the end of request ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unless you use the `@asynchronous` decorator.